# port 5666: Connection refused. In nagios Core

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, nagios3

I have a Nagios core installed and running, and I was trying to setup a Nagios remote host in ubuntu server 22 LTS version. I have done all the for setting up remote host, the same is showing in the Nagios browser also but an error is showing like the connection to the port 5666 is refused.
As per the tutorials I have changed the settings in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`

```
server_address= my_nagios_server_ip4address
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1, my_nagios_server_ip4address
# COMMAND ARGUMENT PROCESSING
dont_blame_nrpe=0
/dev/sda2
```

restarted nrpe service after that
`$service nagios-nrpe-server restart`

I have tried adding Firewall rules

```
To Action From 
-- ------ ---- 
443 ALLOW Anywhere 
80/tcp ALLOW Anywhere 
22/tcp ALLOW Anywhere 
5666 ALLOW Anywhere 
5666/tcp ALLOW Anywhere 
443 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6) 
80/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6) 
22/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6) 
5666 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6) 
5666/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: I have tried adding Firewall rules

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                 ALLOW       Anywhere
5666                    ALLOW       Anywhere
5666/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere
443 (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5666 (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5666/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)